# Calculating the average time based on total on a Array

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash, trading

Using Lodash and moment packages.

I have a array with objects. Each has a 2 important properties.

Assume the trades are like this

```
const trades = [
  { RealizedPnL: 20, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-16T19:04:16.2163527' },
  { RealizedPnL: 30, OpenTradeAt: '2023-01-23T13:45:32.4256713' },
  { RealizedPnL: 10, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-03T08:12:01.0152846' },
  { RealizedPnL: -15, OpenTradeAt: '2023-01-10T16:39:52.1198765' },
  { RealizedPnL: -5, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-24T11:27:56.3297178' },
  { RealizedPnL: -5, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-24T11:27:56.3297178' },
  { RealizedPnL: 25, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-26T13:17:56.3297128' },
  { RealizedPnL: 60, OpenTradeAt: '2023-02-24T17:27:56.3297178' }
];
```

I want to know based on this information whetever the best time is to take a trade in average. Let's say there are 4 very good trades (positive RealizedPnL) at around 17:00 and there is 2 (positive RealizedPnL) trades at arround 20:00 then the best trade in average shall be 17:00 in this case.

This is basically a indication for which time the trades is best to open based on information from the past.

I want to actually know both the time which the trader is best to open a trade at and the worst time to trade but I want to focus on best time first.

---

What I already got:

```
const timeRegex = /(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
const times = _.map(trades, (trade) => {
  const [, hours, minutes] = trade.OpenTradeAt.match(timeRegex);
  return { time: `${hours}:${minutes}`, PnL: trade.RealizedPnL };
});
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "time": "19:04",
        "PnL": 20
    },
    {
        "time": "13:45",
        "PnL": 30
    },
    {
        "time": "08:12",
        "PnL": 10
    },
    {
        "time": "16:39",
        "PnL": -15
    },
    {
        "time": "11:27",
        "PnL": -5
    },
    {
        "time": "11:27",
        "PnL": -5
    },
    {
        "time": "13:17",
        "PnL": 25
    },
    {
        "time": "17:27",
        "PnL": 60
    }
]
```

Is this even possible to know with these information?

Comment: To compute values to rank, you would need to define a time resolution (e.g.) one hour intervals, and possibly do rolling/overlapping time intervals. Also, you would need to define clear rules to rank the quality (e.g. is 4 +values and 1 negative value in an interval better, worse or equivalent to 3 +values and no negatives, and does the magnitude of the score matter e.g. is +50 alone better than a +10 and +15. My feeling is that there is a degree of subjectivity to the scoring and a visual tool, such as a bar chart or scatter plot might be more useful?

Comment: Oh yes the magnitude of the score matter. If one time has performed 50 profits and 2 timeframe total of 35 (10, 15) then the time with 50 is better. And yes there would need to be a time resolution that map the time together. I was thinking of 30 minutes. Eg: each time is related to a other if there is 30 minutes in between. Other than that thank you for the suggestion about the visual bar chart will put that on my idea list.

Comment: Although it would be difficult to show overlapping intervals, A bar chart with + and - values above and below the horizontal axis could be used where the height of the bar is the number of events or, since you said the magnitude matters, the summed magnitudes. That would give a good visual for a subjective decision. Similarly, a scatter plot with + and - values above a time axis would give a good impression of clustered trends.

Comment: I understand what you said but for now I would like to have the output in a object orientated as my post is saying.